# Bootstrapping CI around variance ratio from random regression model

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, bootstrap, random-generation

I am interested in the ratio of random slope variance from a random slope and intercept model. I fit the model using lme4 as

```r
model_slopes <- lme4::lmer(trait ~ covariate + (covariate | individual_ID), 
                           data = example_dataset)
```

and calculate the ratio as :

> **$R_S^2$ = ${V_S
> \over V_p}$ = ${V_VV_X +\mu^2V_V\over V_F+V_I+V\phi+V_R}$**

Where $V_S$ is the random slope variance that is calculated using

- $V_V$ - random-slope variance from the model
- $V_X$ - Variance in covariate from the raw data
- μ - Mean of covariate calculated from the raw data
- and $V_P$ is the total variance in response

I want to estimate uncertainity associated with $R_S^2$ using bootstrapping. My questions are these:

1. What type of bootstrapping should I use - parametric? case?
2. I have a repeated measure of 5 observation per individual. How can I do parametric bootstrapping keeping this data structure in mind?
3. Since I use variance in covariate from the raw data, how can I estimate this for each bootstrap sample?

When I sample with replacement the individuals (non-parametric bootstrapping), I get a distribution of estimate which is not centered around the estimate from the model (little triangles). Here is an example where the yellow distribution is for $R_S^2$ and green one for $V_S$ for different values of repeated measures per individual from a simulation:

[image]

Comment: The sampling distribution of $R_S^2$ does not need to be symmetric, but I would expect it to include the value from the original sample. Perhaps you could increase the number of Bootstrap samples.

Comment: The distribution is from 50000 bootstrapped samples

Comment: When I look further into the components of $R_S^2$, I see the variance in random slope $V_V$ is the one that does not include the value from the original sample with non-parametric bootsrapping. I am not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use non-parametric Bootstrap by sampling with replacement from the subjects in your dataset. A simple R function to do this, is the following:

```r
make_bootSample <- function (workDF, subject_id, seed = 1L) {
    # random seed
    if (!exists(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv))
        runif(1L)
    RNGstate <- get(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv)
    on.exit(assign(".Random.seed", RNGstate, envir = .GlobalEnv))
    # set seed
    set.seed(seed)
    
    ids <- workDF[[subject_id]]
    unq_ids <- unique(ids)
    ids <- factor(ids, levels = unq_ids)
    new_ids <- sample(unq_ids, replace = TRUE)
    new_workDF <- vector("list", length(unq_ids))
    for (i in seq_along(unq_ids)) {
        keep <- workDF[[subject_id]] == new_ids[i]
        data_i <- workDF[keep, ]
        data_i[[subject_id]] <- i
        new_workDF[[i]] <- data_i
    }
    do.call("rbind", new_workDF)
}
```

Comment: I tried that and have edited the post to show the outcome from non-parametric bootstrapping. I am guessing that it is because it does not make any assumptions about the data and is more useful for the estimates related to the sample rather than the population?